# JQuery click function not adding all the CSS classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

here's JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var btn = $(".menuBtn");
    var menu = $(".menuBox");
    var content = $(".container");

    var isOpen = 0;

    btn.click(function() {
        if(isOpen == 0) {
            isOpen = 1;

            menu.addClass("menuOpen");
            content.addClass("opened");
            btn.addClass("opened");
        } else if(isOpen == 1) {
            isOpen = 0;

            menu.removeClass("menuOpen");
            content.removeClass("opened");
            btn.removeClass("opened");
        }
    });
});
```

When the button is clicked, `menu` gets the correct class. But `content` and `btn` doesn't get the `opened` class like they're supposed to. Atleast I don't think so.

The `opened` class just contains a `left: 60%;` parameter. The goal is to make those two classes set the `left` tag to 60%.

I'm quite new to JQuery but I think this should work just fine. But I guess there's some sort of rule that I've missed.

I can also add that the `content` and `btn` classes have a `left: 0;` on them as default.

This is my HTML:

```
    <span class="menuBtn">
        &#9776;
    </span>
    <div class="menuBox">
        <!-- This is just now a black box -->
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        Website content

    </div>

    </div>
```

CSS of the `container` class. The menuBtn is pretty much the same when it comes to positioning:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transition: left .2s;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: can you create a Plunker?

Comment: May be it is applied but in your css there is no property like `position`? Show you CSS too.

Comment: @Justinas Added to the OP

Comment: @RohanKumar There is a `position: absolute;` on all the classes

Comment: Inspect the html with browser's dev tools, after you click the button. I think you'll find they have the class

Comment: @KScandrett ok so they got the class. But for some weird reason they don't get affected by the left attribute..

Comment: It works just fine for me, take a look, https://jsfiddle.net/06u4jqft/ . Just rightclick on the menu and hit inspect. then when you click they all get a new class

Comment: Use `left: 60% !important;` in `opened` css class. Otherwise, your code has no problems.

Comment: @RohanKumar That did it. Didn't really think about that.. Thanks!